# Using BERT embeddings for Seq2Seq model building

Tags: tensorflow, word-embedding, seq2seq, bert-language-model, glove

Earlier I've used Glove embedding to build the seq2seq model for text summarization, Now I want to change the Glove with BERT to see the performance of the model. For this, I used the bert-as-service feature from https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service But giving the input to the model the same as Glove failing. How to code this part?

Comment: Can you show some code, how do you put the vectors in the model?